# referencing int in scanf

Tags: c++, c, scanf

This question may look stupid but that's how people learn :).I learned C++ where you didn't have to worry about referencing int variable in cin>> . Today I was learning filehandling in C for school work but When I tried to run the program with this syntax, I got error.

```
scanf("%d\n %s\n",id, name);
```

But when I referenced id in scanf, the error was gone.i-e;

```
scanf("%d\n %s\n",&id, name);
```

Why is this so? I will be very thankful for answering this noob question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) is a function that expects a pointer to a variable so that it can store the value it reads into the location pointed to by the pointer.

`name` is presumably some sort of (`char`?) array, so the identifier for that variable already refers to an address, so the `&` operator is not necessary. It is however for the `int` variable (I'm assuming `id` is some sort of `int`) you need to get the address to pass to `scanf` in the call.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` needs the address of `id` so it scan store the value there. It has no interest in its current value which is what it is given in your first case.

Answer (score 0):

scanf is a C function. C doesn't have references, so to alter a variable scanf needs to be passed a pointer to that variables location. C++ has references so it doesn't need pointers, although it could use them also.

Answer (score 0):

**scanf()** requires the address of the variable to store the data into.

In case of an integer, the "**&**" symbol is required to refer to the address of the integer variable. But in case of string it is not required to use "**&**" as a string is already a pointer to a character array.